# Creating a new branch with different caplitalization in windows

Tags: windows, git

I can create a branch on windows that has different capitalization than an already existing branch.  But windows cannot handle branches with different cases.  Is this a bug in git?

Here are the details:

I am new to git.  Say I clone a remote repository using the windows `git` command line.

```
$git clone remoteURL local
```

Now, if I list the branches, I get something like:

```
$git branch --all
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/foo
```

I can now do:

```
$git branch FOO
```

and git will succeed, and I get:

```
$git branch --all
FOO
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/foo
```

and if I then push FOO to the remote repository, I now have two branches with the same name, but different capitalization which git on windows does not like, nor work well with.

This strikes me as a bug.  Is it?  Or is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out why Windows complains is to learn a little more about how Git manages branches.

A branch in Git is basically a text file inside `.git/refs` that contains the Commit SHA representing the tip of that branch. Branch names in Git translate to text files on your hard disk.

- Branch: foo
- File: .git/refs/heads/foo
- Branch: foo/bar
- File: .git/refs/heads/foo/bar

File names and file paths on Windows are not case sensitive. If the remote Git repository is on Mac OS or Linux, file paths *are* case sensitive on those operating systems. A branch called "foo" and another called "FOO" are different branches to Git on those OS's.

The remote server sounds like it is a Linux box. On Windows, branches named "foo" and "FOO" would map to the *same* file path: `.git/refs/heads/foo` instead of two different branches like Git expects.

Comment: Oh, I understand why Windoze complains.  What I don't understand, is why at branch creation time, it doesn't check it's repository of known remote branch names, and say, "dude, there's one of those already!"

Comment: Because "foo" and "FOO" aren't necessarily the same branch. It depends on the operation system of the remote repository, which Git doesn't know.

Comment: if I have a remote/origin/foo branch, I can do, "git clone ...", "git branch foo" and that will work, even though the local branch name is identical to the remote branch name.  Does that make sense to you?  I'll admit, that it confuses me.

Comment: It makes (perfect?) sense. You have a local branch named "foo" and the remote named origin has a branch named "foo". In Git, there are no logical connections between local and remote branches unless you set up tracking via `git checkout -t origin/foo`.